# Parsing the value of an integer using a string?

Tags: c#

I have Script2 which has int restaurant1Current, along with several other variables with similar names. On another script, I'm trying to parse the value of restaurant1Current using this code. category is a string with the value of "restaurant1".

```
string currentStringBuffer = "Script2." + category + "Current";
int currentNumber = int.Parse(currentStringBuffer);
```

I want to be able to use the same code as I change the value of category hence the need to parse it using a string instead of referencing the variable directly. Is this the correct syntax or am I missing something? As is the code tells me "The input string is not in the correct format" but when debugging it shows that the string contains the value "Script2.restaurant1Current" which again is an int. So why wouldn't I be able to parse the value to currentNumber in the next line?

Answer (score -3):

```
public Enum Categories{
Restauraunt,
Grocer,
Bank

}
```

Enum stands for enumeration, it is a numbered list. with this particular enum,
Categories.Bank =2; so you can call or assign.

```
something.category=2;
```

or

```
int rando = Categories.Bank
```

Comment: what happens when the category is `science1`?

Comment: who said anything about a laundromat? OP hasn't elaborated what category is. for the string shes showing this should work.

Comment: not now that she has elaborated. an answer can only be as good as the question.... at least i offer help besides ' go read something'

Comment: though i will be editing my answer as it is no longer correct as you point out.

Comment: @PrinceOfRavens thank you but I'm getting "cannot convert from char to string for chars[19].

Comment: no @Jessica im sorry sometimes its hard to get a good answer. keep doing what you are doing, and learning. thats why i come here too. i am doing something similar with an enum assigning and `Element` to a creature, like pokemon. the problem for you is, while it makes category an int, it will require you to rework your formula a bit.